# Dynamic GroupBy - linq.Dynamic

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, dynamic

I am trying to create a drag and drop filter/grouping control using MVC. I have got all the drag and drop stuff working fine. However I cannot seem to get the `GroupBy` to work the way I want it to.

Currently what I have is something like this.

```
IQueryable<Equipment> lst = doSearch("EquipmentType_ID", "Manufacturer_ID");
var news = lst.GroupBy("idLocation.Name", "ID");
```

When this returns it comes back without any reference to the `<Equipment>` however when I step through the `dynamic.cs` code it seems to have references to `<Equipment>` all the way through.

If I do something like this it works fine

```
var news = lst.GroupBy(z => z.idLocation.Name);
```

But I need that to be dynamically generated depending on what the user has selected so I have to use the linq.Dynamic `GroupBy`.

I then return the list as a partial view and loop through the model and display the results.

So, how can I return a strongly typed list from linq.dynamic?

---

This is what I am currently doing. It works but I was hoping to be able to not do any foreach loops or anything like that.

```
List<ZITS_DAL.Equipment> lst = doSearch(equipmentType_ID, manufacturer_ID)

var news = lst.AsQueryable().GroupBy(headers, "it");
ZITS_BO.ViewModels.vmDragControl vm = new ViewModels.vmDragControl();
vm.lst =  new List<IGrouping<string, ZITS_DAL.Equipment>>();
            foreach (IGrouping<string,ZITS_DAL.Equipment> t in news)
            {
               vm.lst.Add(t);
            }
```

The vmDragControl viewmodel is the following.

```
 List<IGrouping<string, ZITS_DAL.Equipment>> lst
```

Then in my model I have 2 foreach loops. One on the list of IGroupings and a nested one on the Equipment in Igrouping.

It works but is kinda slow... Anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: So right now i have the following in case people were wondering.
List<ZITS_DAL.Equipment> lst = doSearch(equipmentType_ID, manufacturer_ID)

Comment: What do you mean “it comes back without any reference to the <Equipment>”? What *does* come back?

Comment: You can click on the links further down in this. They are part of some c# examples from microsoft. Its a custom built class that you just include and reference. allows you to add string variables and such into lambda expressions...
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx